# How to prevent Excel automatically adding a number to duplicate column header in table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I am using Excel in Office 365.

I formatted a section of a spreadsheet as a table.  In the header row I want several columns to have the exact same heading. Here's a nonsensical example to illustrate the issue. This is what I want:

[image: illustration]

But this is what I get when I try to type (or copy+paste) the second set of headings:

[image]

As you can see, Excel added "2" to the second set of headings.

(Note that in my example, I've manually added a "super-header" (which is not part of the table), so I know what is meant by looking at it.)

It seems that Excel doesn't permit duplicate heading labels in a section that has been formatted as table. My workaround has been to manually add trailing spaces after the text I want to duplicate.

In my actual spreadsheet, I have many sets like that and I want to just paste in duplicated headings across the row. But Excel adds numbers serially across the row and the only way I've found to get what I want is the workaround I mention above.

I would like to "convince" Excel to trust that I know what I'm doing in how I name columns and not try to "fix" it for me. I checked the Excel options and searched for this issue online, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. Smart tables allows to refer to a data using column name - so it must be unique.

Comment: Consider rearranging your data into 3 columns (animal[?], eat drink), then pivot it and you should be able to get your result visually.

Answer (score 1):

I appended leading / training blank spaces to avoid this.

Note: Your use-case might be different, but the above worked for me.

Comment: this is a very useful trick for repeating value like Q1/Q2/Q3/Q4 etc.. where we want to show multiple quarters for multiple years

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Formula Bar where your text is and delete/backspace the 2 then click on the checkmark/enter button on the left between the X and fx buttons. That cleared it for me.